# How to display my header background color even when typing <!DOCTYPE html >

Tags: html, css, web

I hope you all feel well.

So I have written my HTML code but I forgot to add `<!DOCTYPE html>` at the beginning of the document and my code was working so fine, but when I went back to add it (the `<!DOCTYPE html>` ) the header background color disappeared and I don't know why and I tried to get it back but it still dispeared, does anyone know tell what is th problem please?

```css
    .HeaderContainer {
        background-position: center;
        position: fixed;
        text-align: right;
        width: 100%;
        height: 150px;
        padding: 20px;
    
    }
    
    
    .background {
        
        background: url(annie-spratt-qyAka7W5uMY-unsplash.jpg);
        height: 100vh;
        background-size: cover;
        bacground-position: center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-attachment: fixed;
        position: relative;
        filter: brightness(70%);   
        min-width: 100%;
        max-width: 100%; 
       /* background-size: 1920px 2400px;*/
    }
    
    
        
    
    
    .list { 
            list-style: none;
            margin-top: 30px;
            position: absolute;    
            color: white;
            top: 0px;
            left: 50%;
    
    }
    
    
    
    .list .link {
        color: white;
        text-decoration: none;
        padding: 20px 20px;
        font-size: 30px;
        text-align: center; 
    }
    
    .list .link:hover {
        background-color: white;
        border-radius: 7px;
        color: black;   
        font-weight: bold;  
    }
    
    
    .dropDownList {
        float: right; 
        paddin: 20px;
        margin: 0;
    }
    
    .dropDownListButton {  
        color: white;
        text-decoration: none;
        padding: 12px 12px;
        font-size: 30px;
        text-align: right;
        display: inline;
        
    }
    
    .dropDownList:hover .dropDownListButton {
        background-color: white;
        border-radius: 7px;
        color: black;   
    
    }
    
    .dropDownListContent {  
      display: none;
      position: relative;
      background-color: #F8C471;
      border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;
      border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;
    }
    
    .dropDownListContent .links {
      float: none;  
      color: black;
      padding: 12px 16px;
      text-decoration: none;
      display: block;
    }
    
    .dropDownList:hover .dropDownListContent {
      display: block; 
    }
    
    .links:hover {
         text-decoration: underline;
         font-weight: bold;
    }
```

```html
    <header>
               
                <div class = "headerContainer" id = "myHeader">
                  
                  <div class ="list" id = "myList"> <!-- To list the top-bar links -->
                       <a class = "link" href = "#" id = "home">Home</a>               
                       
                       
                       <div class = "dropDownList">
                         
                        <div class = "dropDownListButton"> Menu1 <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>   </div> 
                     
                         <div class = "dropDownListContent">
                            <a href = "#" class = "links">  item1</a>
                            <a href = "#" class = "links"> item2 </a>
                            <a href = "#" class = "links"> item3 </a>                    
                            
                         </div>                      
                       
                       </div>
                       
                        <div class = "dropDownList">
                         
                        <div class = "dropDownListButton"> Menu2  <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>  </div>
                         <div class = "dropDownListContent"> 
                            <a href = "#" class = "links"> Item1 </a>
                         </div>                      
                       
                       </div>
                       
                       
                       
                       <div class = "dropDownList">
                         
                        <div class = "dropDownListButton"> Menu3 <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>  </div>
                         <div class = "dropDownListContent"> 
                            <a href = "#" class = "links"> item1 </a>
                            
                         </div>                      
                       
                       </div>
                      
                   </div>
                   
                   <a href =    
                  
                </div>
```

Comment: HeaderContainer is not the same as headerContainer...

Comment: Doctype has no impact to CSS colors.

Comment: Which element's background color?

Comment: headerContainer class is the one with background color

Comment: Yeah that's weird because as I know doctype has no effects but when I added it the background color dispeared